# how to change value of a column w.e.f (with effective from) a certain date

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to amend the values in GST column (w.e.f) with effective from certain dates.

```
Date         GST
5/3/2020     5%
5/2/2020     5%
5/1/2020     5%
4/30/2020    5%
4/29/2020    5%
4/28/2020    5%
```

Example it was announced GST w.e.f 1st May will be adjusted to 8%.
Would like to achieve like this:

```
Date         GST
5/3/2020     8%
5/2/2020     8%
5/1/2020     8%
4/30/2020    5%
4/29/2020    5%
4/28/2020    5%
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this a DatetimeIndex or strings?

Comment: the date is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df
        Date GST
0   5/3/2020  5%
1   5/2/2020  5%
2   5/1/2020  5%
3  4/30/2020  5%
4  4/29/2020  5%
5  4/28/2020  5%
```

convert to a DataFrame with DatetimeIndex first.

```
>>> df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])).drop('Date', 1)
>>> df
           GST
Date          
2020-05-03  5%
2020-05-02  5%
2020-05-01  5%
2020-04-30  5%
2020-04-29  5%
2020-04-28  5%
```

Now use index based assignment.

```
>>> df[:'2020-05-01'] = '8%'
>>> df
           GST
Date          
2020-05-03  8%
2020-05-02  8%
2020-05-01  8%
2020-04-30  5%
2020-04-29  5%
2020-04-28  5%
```

Comment: thanks, just to further add on if only to change the particular column:
`df[:'2020-05-01', 'GST'] = '8%'`

Comment: @distalr close, you'd have to use `df.loc[:'2020-05-01', 'GST']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df.loc[df['Date'] >= datetime(2020, 5, 1), 'GST'] = '8%'
```

If your `Date` column is string type then you convert to `to_datetime` in pandas as:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```